# React Native - Flex

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet, react-native-flexbox, react-native-screens

I have two components in a screen. One is an `Image` and other is a `View`.
I give `flex:1` to main view and give `flex:0.7` to image and `flex:0.3` to view.

```js
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const OnboardingItem = ({ item }) => {
    const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

    return (
        <View style={[{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }, { width }]}>
            <Image
                style={[styles.image, { width, resizeMode: 'contain', }]}
                source={item.image}
            />
            <View style={{ flex: 0.3 }}>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text>{item.description}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default OnboardingItem

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        flex: 0.7,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
})
```

I am trying to give `flex:1` to main view and `flex:0.7` to image. So, Image take 70% of screen and `flex:0.3` to a view. So, View take other 30% of screen.

---

But the problem is it not taking the hole screen.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `OnboardingItem` `flex: 1` with fixed window height, so your items inside will always have 0.7 and 0.3 height of the screen.

```
const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

<View style={[{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', }, { width, height }]}>
```

I can see from screenshot that you probably render two `OnboardingItem` components inside parent component. If two components with `flex: 1` are rendered inside one parent component, then both of them will takes half of the available space. More info on how flexbox works in react-native in the official [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox).